# Running the command node dist/index.js gives an error related to Typescript files in src folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have a GraphQL and Apollo server https://github.com/AdhamAH/Film-and-actors-list/tree/main/server

After running `tsc -p .` then `node dist/index.js` I am getting the error from a TS file in the `src` folder like this

```
Film-and-actors-list\server\src\entities\Films.ts:1

import {Field, ObjectType} from "type-graphql";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

After searching for hours with no luck I had an idea to delete the `src` folder and when I run `node dist/index.js` the server starts with no error

I tried to change the `tsconfig.json`options but no luck

My `tsconfig`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

And my `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "film-actor-list-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w src --ext ts --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/AdhamAH/Film-and-actors-list.git"
  },
  "author": "A.AboHasson",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AdhamAH/Film-and-actors-list/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AdhamAH/Film-and-actors-list#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/connect-redis": "^0.0.17",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "@types/redis": "^2.8.32",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.5.0",
    "connect-redis": "^6.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "graphql": "15.3.0",
    "redis": "^3.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.40",
    "typeorm-encrypted": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I figured it out***

The problem was that I had a file `ormconfig.json` with following

```
{
  "type": "sqlite",
  "database": "./db.sqlite3",
  "entities": ["./src/entities/*.ts"],
  "synchronize": true
}
```

So it looks like that when I start the server it is loading the TS files from `entities` folder

What I did that I added this configuration to `index.ts` like this

```js
const connection = await createConnection({
      "type": "sqlite",
      "database": "./db.sqlite3",
      "entities": [User, Films],
      "synchronize": true
  })
```

With this I imported the entities and solved the problem

Comment: I just changed `"entities": ["./src/entities/*.ts"],` from `ormconfig.json` to  `"entities": ["./dist/entities/*.js"],` , and it works fine.